# gdm graphical login prompt problem (OpenSUSE 11.2)

Tags: gnome, opensuse, gdm

I'm trying to figure out why the graphical login prompt won't show up at the login page. I see the wallpaper just fine, but the graphical login prompt won't show up no matter how long I wait.

So, In the console, I've done `init 3` to shut down gdm and then restarted it with `init 5`. The problem still persists.

I downloaded and installed kdm and set it as the default display manager through editing `/etc/systemconfig/displaymanager`. It worked fine, except that the main menu and many other items in the panels are gone. So I removed gdm with zypper and then reinstalled it again. I set the gdm as the default display manager and restarted gdm. The same problem shows up again. So I tried to bypass the login page entirely by enabling autologin. I put my username in the autologin section of `/etc/systemconfig/displaymanager` and restarted gdm. No go, I still get the same problem.

I'm thinking it mightn't be gdm related and that something else is interfering with gdm startup, but I'm stumped at this point. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you supply your `pstree` or, better, `ps axjf`, so that we could find out at least which part of gdm is stuck, (simple-slave, session worker, greeter)?

Comment: (just to make sure) do you an external display connected ? In my setup I don't see the login prompt until I move the mouse to the 2nd display.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`cat /etc/sysconfig/desktop`

That should tell what your `DISPLAYMANAGER` and `DESKTOP` are set to. This file is used by `/etc/X11/xinit/Xclients` to determine which desktop to start.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

Error with 2 users both having same uuid bug.
Removing a second user from /etc/passwd and rebooting allows gdm to work normally.

Post #9

https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?311366-gdm-login-screen-stopped-appearing-graphical-login-not-possible